# How to to really type cast a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Item as superclass and there are two subclasses under it.

When the user input the information at the **first time**, the input parameters are included in the hash of `params[:item]`. And I instantiate the concrete type according to the input.

```
# instantitate the concrete type according to the input
type_of_item = Object::const_get(inputs[:type])
@item = type_of_item.new
```

When the validation is failed, I put the user back to the new page. The user input the data again

**However**, this time, the input parameters will be included in the hash of `params[:bidding_item]` or `params[:direct_item` where bidding_item and direct_item are the subclass of **Item**

I try to do something like:

```
format.html do
  @item.becomes(Item)
  render :action=>"new"
end
```

I hope every time the input parameters will be include in `params[:item]` so that I can get the data in the same way at every time, but it doesn't work.

Now, I solve my problem with. But I think it is not a good practice at all.

```
# form input
inputs = params[:item] || params[:bidding_item] || params[:direct_item]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `new` view file you can add the `:as` option to the `form_for` tag.

```
form_for @item, :as => :item do |form|
```

This will mean that the parameters will always come through as `params[:item]` independent of what the object type is.

Comment: I'm not sure how to "really cast a model". This will fix your immediate problem though.

Comment: Thanks :) You understand `form_for` so well :)